# Retrive content of a row with maximum id from grouped rows

Tags: mysql

I got a mysql table with following data

```
commodityId  ItemCode       ItemName                SellingPrice
469          8901764362804  MM Pulpy Orange Pet     18
692          8901764362309  MM Pulpy 65             65
719          8901764362804  MM Pulpy Orange Pet     20
1019         8901764362804  MM Pulpy Orange Pet     20
1041         8901764362804  MM Pulpy Orange Pet     20
```

Please note that always the recent entry of an item will have maximum commodityId. Now I want get the recent Selling price of an item. I wrote the following code

```
select max(commodityId), itemname, sellingprice from purchases 
group by itemcode order by commodityId desc;
```

Output of this code is

```
692     MM Pulpy 65            65
1041    MM Pulpy Orange Pet    18
```

I am getting **18** as selling price which is the selling price of oldest entry. I want the selling price of recent entry that is **20**.  I need that recent selling price for all items that are present in my table. Can someone suggest the change in the query?

I have to use that selling price as part of another query where I join 4 tables.

Comment: what is itemcode ? Please post the complete details.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT B.MAX_COMM_ID, A.itemname, A.sellingprice 
from purchases A
INNER JOIN (select itemcode, max(commodityid) AS MAX_COMM_ID
            from purchases
            group by itemcode ) B ON A.itemcode=B.itemcode AND A.commodityid=B.MAX_COMM_ID
;
```

Comment: I upvoted you, but why select `B.MAX_COMM_ID` instead of `A.commodityid`?  Why not just do `SELECT A.*` ?

Comment: Just to point out the field,  and based on fields listed in question.  Yes, you can write A.commoodityid or A.* if you prefer it.